# Setting database dynamically based on current user

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

I've this project where a different database should be used based on the current user.
I'm using codeigniter with the Datamapper extension.

Ideal would be to set a different connection group in a controller which I can use in my datamapper models like:

```
var $db_params = 'user_specific';
```

However unlike the config params, the database params don't seem to be accessible from inside a controller.
I did find a way where you needed to pass a variable ($db) when creating a new datamapper object in an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448506/connecting-to-mulitple-databases-with-dmz-datamapper) question.

```
$customers = new customer(NULL, $db);
// The NULL I would need becuase the constructor expects an ID or nothing by default
```

However, most models would use the dynamic settings so it is a lot of work adding the $db variable everywhere...
Is there any other solution so I can just do

```
$customer = new customer();

// And in my model use the dynamic 'config' settings like
var $db_params = 'user_specific';
```

It would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

An even simpler way would it be to connect to the database when you already retrieved the connection group you want to connect to. In your controller use:

```
class SomeController extends MY_Controller{

    public function index(){

        $connection_group = getCustomerConnectionGroup(); //example only
        $this->load->database($connection_group);

    }

}
```

While you cannot change the connection group during runtime, work it around by returning the connection ID and store it into a class property of MY_Controller

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    protected $mydb;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->connect_to('default');
    }

    public function connect_to($group)
    {
        $this->mydb = $this->load->database($group, true);
    }

}

?>
```

Now in your normal Controllers you will be using the following

```
class SomeController extends MY_Controller{

    public function index(){

        $connection_group = getCustomerConnectionGroup(); //example only
        $this->connect_to($connectionGroup);

    }

}
```

Note that by doing this you need to use

$this->mydb->method();

troughout your application.

Comment: I see where you are going with this, but since I'm using the Datamapper ORM I don't need to connect to the database in my controller(s). The models take care of this.